# Asus EEE PC Seashell series Intel® Atom™ CPU N2600 @ 1.60GHz × 4.. Best Ubuntu version/flavor for my

Tags: drivers, 13.04, intel-graphics, eeepc, cedarview

I am new to Ubuntu...because of my Windows problems i completely erased it and installed through USB while WiFi On, the latest version of Ubuntu13.04.. Everything is working fine and perfect. but it is real real dead slow.

The below is the configuration i got through settings .
Processor : Intel® Atom™ CPU N2600 @ 1.60GHz × 4
Memory : 2GB
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)
OS Type : 32-bit
Disk : 312.8GB

Please suggest me which flavor of ubuntu is best to get the good speed.

Comment: This is primarily a **Cedarview** issue, and you will need to stick with **32-bit**.

Comment: Please read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/290515/how-to-install-intel-cedarview-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-10-or-13-04

Comment: 12.04.0 with kernel 3.2 (and only 3.2) works great. The Xorg packages also have to be the versions that ship with 12.04.0. Do not update past the 3.2 kernel