# How to install Intel CedarView drivers on Ubuntu 12.10 or higher?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, gpu-driver, cedarview

I am looking for instructions on how to install cedarview graphics drivers on Ubuntu 13.04 32bit.

My graphics hardware is a **GMA3600** aka **Power VR SGX545**.

EDIT: It seems that they are not in Raring yet, but only Precise:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/it/precise-updates/cedarview-graphics-drivers

EDIT2: they seem to be closed source.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cedarview-graphics-drivers confirms that these drivers are available only for Precise.

Comment: is it somehow possible to install them for 13.04 nonetheless?

Comment: Have you tried Intel EMGD drivers, I think they can compile with Kernel 3.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am fairly sure this is impossible. The problem is that CedarView drivers are closed-source, outdated and Intel is no longer updating them. The driver supports **3.2 kernel only**, and its DKMS module fails to compile under **any** newer kernel (including 13.04's kernel: 3.8).

Because the driver's source is closed, neither Canonical nor Ubuntu developers are capable of modyfing it to be compatible with newer kernels. Also there is no way you could patch it on your own by following some magic guide, for such patch will never exist as long as the driver's source is closed.

**So what to do then?**

There are several options.

1. **Convince Intel to open-source the driver.** This way they would not need to manage it, as the Ubuntu community might hack on it to apply updates. However, I expect it's clear how difficult it may be to convince Intel to such move.
2. **Convince Intel to update the driver to a newer kernel.** This may be difficult too, considering the fact they gave so little love to this driver, and it is definitelly not of their interest anymore.
3. **Use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin, 32bit**. While 12.04 currently uses 3.5 kernel, you can install 3.2 manually. If you do, cedarview drivers should install correctly. Make sure not to use the -pae kernel, as is also not supported. Also, you **need** to use the 32bit system, as the driver does not support any other architecture.

Yeah, I am aware this all is utterly annoying, and super-silly. Please direct all your complains in this matter to Intel, as it is only them who is responsible for this absurd.

Comment: thanks for the details. it seems my chances to run ubuntu on this hardware are quite low... :-(

Comment: I have found this
https://github.com/thomas001/cedarview-drm - but I have absolutely no idea how to use it (the instructions are kind of unclear, and when I tried to follow them I ended with an unbootable system somehow)

Answer (score 1):

I think this guide is what you're looking for: http://ef.gy/ubuntu-cedarview-drivers

Comment: thanks, but these packages cant be found `E: Unable to locate package cedarview-drm
E: Unable to locate package libva-cedarview-vaapi-driver
E: Unable to locate package cedarview-graphics-drivers
`

Comment: are you sure you're using a 32bit version of ubuntu? I'm not an ubuntu expert, maybe the packages haven't been updated for 13.04 yet

Comment: i am on 32bit yes, and it seems the sources are closed source

Answer (score 1):

Since CedarView can only be compiled under kernel 3.2, maybe we could try compile this kernel first on 13.04 then we compile cedardview

For me,the only drawback for 13.04 regarding the native graphic driver is that the screen rotation doesn't work, except that the resolution is perfect and everything else is good

I'm using Linux Mint 15, Mate Edition

UPD: It's not just about the kernel, but also xserver version.. cedarvew is not supporting new xserver versions according to:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cedarview-drm-drivers/+bug/1132584/comments/4
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cedarview-drm-drivers/+bug/1132584

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment on the post of Rafal directly. I thought i might just add here that pae seems to be supported now.

I am running 12.04 32bit Ubuntu on my EeePc. If you have problems with the system randomly freezing try an older kernel than the highest 3.2.0-82. For my Asus Eee PC R011CX 3.2.0-38-generic-pae seems to be the most stable. It has ok graphics, no random freezes.

Good Luck to everyone with this stupid setup.
And to everyone at Intel reading this, next setup will be AMD. I feel left alone with my purchase!