# My ubuntu runs in slow motion on ubuntu 13.04 asus 1015cx

Tags: 13.04, intel-graphics, asus, eeepc, cedarview

My specs:

**my Asus EeePC 1015CX certified by ubuntu 12.04 lts**

asus 1015 cx with gma 3600 graphic card 
intel atom dual core
ubuntu 13.04

My problem:
**I need to use ubuntu 13.04, not 12.04.**

ubuntu 13.04 runs in slow motion on default unity desktop, is it graphic card problem?

when i clicked file, runs in very slow animation on unity.
windows comes up in very slow motion

I can't even use ubuntu 13.04 because so slow.

what's minimal requirement of ubuntu 13.04 or unity desktop?
why is it so slow?
what kind of processes should i take to fix it?
I tried by myself but no good result.

Need some help anyway.
Any ideas ?
maybe i should change hardware lol?
**my Asus EeePC 1015CX certified by ubuntu 12.04 lts !**

Comment: My answer to the follwing question may help you too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289677/unity-low-gfx-mode-not-working-in-13-04

Comment: Please read response for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/290515/how-to-install-intel-cedarview-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-10-or-13-04

Answer (score 1):

To fix the slow graphics performance, after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail, and using Intel GPU, do these two things:

1. Open the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file (it may be blank or non-existent):

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
2. Paste this and save the file:

   ```
   Section "Device"
   Identifier "Card0"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
   #Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
   EndSection
   ```
3. Reboot

**Source:** http://linuxg.net/fix-slow-graphics-performance-on-ubuntu-13-04-intel-gpu/

Comment: nope, doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Ubuntu comfortably with unity on this laptop because of a very weak GPU.
I recommend to install Xubuntu or Lubuntu. These distro's do not require 3D acceleration for GUI working well.

Answer (score -2):

there is a problem of unity 3d and it can not run properly 2 or 3gb ram so u can first remove unity by typing on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge unity
```

after then you install unity 2d by write in terminal

```
 sudo apt-get install unity-2d
```

after installing reboot the pc then u show your ubuntu run faster at speed of 100gb/s

Comment: Are you really sure that typing two less keystrokes for "you" is worth making your post appear childish? (not mentioning the last phrase about speed...). And by the way, James Joyce can go without commas and points, mere mortals should really use them...

Comment: There is no unity2d in Ubuntu 12.10, or newer. The last release with it was 12.04.