# Ubuntu 14.04 slow on Asus EeeBox PC EB1030

Tags: 14.04, graphics, resolution, cedarview

so i upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04 with a usb but i have internet ,my computer is really slow at 1024x768 definition ,everything works super slow ,windows closing and opening and streaming videos ,everything ive used so far.but it works fine at 800x600 definition ,i want it to be fine at the higher definition ,how do i make it run well at 1024x768 ?

in additional drivers nothing shows ,and my computer mirrors by default for some reason ,i tried stopping it from mirroring but  most buttons dont want to work and weird glitches happen ,the system doesnt work well when not mirroring , i dont care if it mirrors or not i just want good performance .thank you in advance for any answers !!
here are the computer specs

Processor   1.8 GHz 8032 Intel® Atom™ Cedar Trail Dual Core CPU

RAM 2 GB DDR3

Memory Speed    1066 MHz

Hard Drive  32 GB

Graphics Coprocessor     Graphics Media Accelerator HD

Wireless Type   802.11B, 802.11G, 802.11n

Number of USB 2.0 Ports     4

Brand Name  Asus

Item model number   EB1030-B003L

Comment: update your graphic card drivers.... i got the same problem. then i update my Nvidia drivers.... :) ....

Comment: Pumayk_26 i updated them and drivers are still missing and ubuntu is still slow ,so i switched Desktop environment to lubuntu and everything runs fast now,im gonna stick with lxde for a while.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Intel CedarView drivers on Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/290515/how-to-install-intel-cedarview-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-10-or-13-04)

Comment: What do you mean by "I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 (...) with a usb but i have internet"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use light weight Windows Manager like gnome-session-flashback.
open terminal ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

then log out, you'll see compiz symbol on up right login corner. click it then choose metacity.

Answer (score 0):

If graphics are very slow use the following to force low graphics mode

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session
```

Remove "compiz" from the RequiredComponents list

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/upstart/sessions/unity7.conf
```

Add these lines after `"export COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE"`:

```
env UNITY_LOW_GFX_MODE="1"

export UNITY_LOW_GFX_MODE
```