# Unable to locate package cedarview-drm

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, gpu-driver, cedarview

```
$ sudo apt-get install cedarview-drm libva-cedarview-vaapi-driver cedarview-graphics-drivers

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package cedarview-drm
E: Unable to locate package libva-cedarview-vaapi-driver
E: Unable to locate package cedarview-graphics-drivers
```

.

```
$ uname -m
i686
```

- Why can't I find these "cedarview-drm packages"?

Comment: It's avalable for 12.04 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got to assume you're running an older version of Ubuntu, on older hardware.  The cedarview drivers seem to be fairly unsupported [according to this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290515/how-to-install-intel-cedarview-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-10-or-13-04), and [another link](https://ef.gy/ubuntu-cedarview-drivers) suggests that they will only operate with a 32 bit version of Ubuntu (12.04?).  [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/x11/cedarview-graphics-drivers) has a downloadable driver for cedarview that you might give a shot at.  Other than that you could start calling and writing to Intel, perhaps?

Comment: I operate Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit. It exist for Ubuntu 12.04 32 bits only?

Comment: That seems to be what I was reading - it is not in the repository of packages for trusty.